# How to remove property from html elements using c#?

Tags: c#, angularjs

I'm new to C#. I am trying to remove particular span tag, which contains image tag. But I don't want remove image tag. If anyone give suggestion or solution, I appreciate you. Thank you.

string content = " span 1  span 2  ";

Comment: can you provide some more details ? post some code maybe ?

Comment: Just now I update my html string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1):

You can check your string value for containing a specific value (in your case span) and then manipulate your string to delete what you want :

**1st** : get the index of opening span tag in your string

```
if (yourString.ToUpper().Contains("SPAN")) // You also can check '<SPAN'
{
    var openIndex = yourString.ToUpper().IndexOf("SPAN", StringComparison.Ordinal);
}
```

**2nd** : get the index of closing span tag

```
var closeIndex = yourString.ToUpper().IndexOf("</SPAN>", StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

**3rd** : manipulate your string, now you know where the span tag starts and ends, so you can substring your original string using those indexes

```
var manipString = yourString.Substring(openIndex, closeIndex + 7) // +7 for '</SPAN>' lenght
```

**4th** : find the '>' closing the opening span tag

```
var closeTagIndex = manipString.IndexOf(">", StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

**5th** : remove the span tags

```
var finalString = manipString.Substring(0, closeTagIndex);
var arr = finalString.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(arr);
var reverseFinalString = new string(arr);
reverseFinalString = reverseFinalString.Substring(0, 7)
arr = reverseFinalString.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(arr);
finalString = new string(arr);
```

- If you only want to delete the span tags if it contains img tag, repeat the process and check for img tag with `string.ToUpper().Contains("<IMG")`
- You probably want to declare variables in another scope that I've done in order to access them
- You probably also want to refactor a little this code and write a `ReverseString()` method to avoid the repetition, the code will be more readable and maintainable

Hope this can help!

Comment: Any explanation to add with the down-vote ? Is your goal to help the community or else ? If it is, I think that you can explain to me what is incorrect in my answer... Thank you in advance !